# TypeScript, extend global Object<K, V> interface

Tags: typescript

It's possible to extend generic `Array` interface

```
declare global {
  interface Array<T> {
    asClist(): Clist<T>
  }
}
```

and write code like `const list = [1, 2].asClist()` and it would infer the type of `list` correctly as `Clist<number>`

**But it won't work with Object**, I tried to use code below but it wont' work because `global Object` seems to not have generic types `<K, V>`

```
declare global {
  interface Object<K, V> {
    asCmap(): Cmap<K, V>
  }
}
```

I try to make code `const cmap = { a: 1, b: 2 }.asCmap()` to infer type of `cmap` correctly as `Cmap<string, number>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the number of type parameters an interface has. `Array` is already generic with one type parameter, `Object` is not generic this is why one works but not the other.

You can achieve the effect you want if you use the `this` parameter and infer the actual object the method was invoked on to a type parameter. With this type parameter you can extract the keys and the values as needed:

```
interface Object {
    asCmap<TThis>(this: TThis): Cmap<keyof TThis, TThis[keyof TThis]>
}

const cmap = { a: 1, b: 2 }.asCmap() // CMap<"a" | "b", number>
```

We can use a conditional type wo widen the type of the key:

```
type Widen<T extends PropertyKey> = PropertyKey extends infer P ? P extends any ? T extends P ? P : never : never : never; 
interface Object {
    asCmap<TThis>(this: TThis): Cmap<Widen<keyof TThis>, TThis[keyof TThis]>
}

const cmap = { a: 1, b: 2 }.asCmap(); // Cmap<string, string
const cmapNr = { 1: 1, b: 2 }.asCmap(); // Cmap<number|string, string>

enum E {
    A, B
}
const cmapEnum = { [E.A]: 1, b: 2 }.asCmap(); // Cmap<string | number, string
```

Comment: That's a neat technique. How, if at all, can we make the inferred type be `Cmap<string, number`> instead of `Cmap<"a" | "b", number>`?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin not sure there is a way to widen the type to string. We could use a conditional type to treat `string`, `number` and symbol cases

Comment: @ShaunLuttin added a widening version

Comment: Do you know if it would it be possible to use it as a getter? `{ a: 1, b: 2 }.asCmap` instead of `{ a: 1, b: 2 }.asCmap()`?

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin no, the `this` parameter trick only works for functions